# How to upload an arbitrary number of files with Swift and Alamofire?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm trying to access a REST API which lets me upload a different number of files, depending on the situation. I've got the following code for Alamofire but I'm not sure how to change this so that I can upload one file, two files, or ten files.

```
    Alamofire.upload(
        .POST,
        "https://httpbin.org/post",
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: farmFileURL, name: "xml-file-farm")
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: farmFileURL, name: "csv-measurement-file-1")
            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: farmFileURL, name: "csv-measurement-file-2")
        },
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)
                }
            case .Failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
        }
    )
```

The problem as I see it is that I can't define an array of files using 'multipartFormData' because that doesn't exist until you're inside the 'upload' method.

Comment: use an array of tuples, with file name and its URL

Comment: @HamzaAnsari Thanks. Care to suggest some sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an array of Tuple which contains `fileName` and its `URL` and simply pass it:

```
 func uploadFiles(files:[(String,NSURL)]){
        Alamofire.upload(
            .POST,
            "https://httpbin.org/post",
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

                for (fileName, fileURL) in files{
                    multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: fileURL, name: fileName)
                }
            },
            encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        debugPrint(response)
                    }
                case .Failure(let encodingError):
                    print(encodingError)
                }
            }
        )
    }
```